# Get Audit log in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

We missed to enable Audit report in my SharePoint 2013 production environment. But management is asking us to provide the list of users who have accessed the site.

Is there any other option to get this data?

Comment: Do you want to enable audit log or just want list of users who access site?

Comment: I want to get list of users data.

Answer (score 7):

The fastest way to do this is to navigate to the User Information List. It displays every user who have accessed the site, which is not to be confused with those who have access to the site. User who have access to the site, but haven't accessed the site won't show up in the user information list.

User Information List

```
http://siteCollectionUrl/_catalogs/users/simple.aspx
```

Answer (score 4):

Your only option is to combine the IIS logs from your front end servers and parse them using a tool like [logparser.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/scriptcenter/dd919274.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). A sample log parser query to find that info would be:

```
SELECT cs-username As User, COUNT(*) as Hits  
FROM c:\yourcombined\logs\W3SVC123\*  
WHERE User Is Not Null GROUP BY User
```